Convergence of Cesaro means

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a dual Banach space $X'$ such that $M:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\|T^n\| <\infty$. Define $$A_nx = \frac1n \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} T^jx\qquad (n\in\mathbb N, x\in X).$$
Show that there exists an operator $P$ and a subnet $(A_{n_k})$ such that $A_{n_k}x$ converges to $Px$ in the weak$^*$-topology for all $x\in X'$.

My attempt: Since $T$ is power-bounded, so for each $x\in X'$, the sequence $(A_nx)$ is bounded, hence by Banach-Alaouglu theorem, it has a weak$^*$-convergent subnet, say $(A_{n_k}x)$.

I'm stuck here because the subnet obtained here depends on $x$ and so if I let $Px$ to be the weak$^*$-limit of this subnet, then I can't guarantee that $P$ is linear. How do I show that there is one subnet for each $x$?


It is worthwhile observing that the sequence is norm convergent to $0$ on the closure of the range of $I-T.$

I'll be happy to be shown a more direct way, but a typical way of proving this is defining a topology on $B(X')$, the weak operator topology, where $A_j\to A$ means that
$$
\langle A_jx,y\rangle\to\langle Ax,y\rangle,\qquad\qquad x\in X',\ y\in X,
$$
where $\langle Ax,y\rangle$ denotes the usual duality pairing, i.e., $\langle Ax,y\rangle=(Ax)(y)$. One then mimics the proof of Banach-Alaoglu, to show that closed balls in $B(X')$ are compact in the weak-operator topology. Now, since $\{A_n\}$ is bounded, there exists a convergent subnet.
